# mysql find insert timestamp

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to sort rows in a select query by the insert timestamp without having a column for timestamp.
So i want to find the rows inserted recently, but there is no column that records insert timestamp. Is here any internal record for each row?

There is no primary key,foreign key for the table.

Comment: If you have an auto-incrementing integer as your primary key you could use that?

Comment: If you dont have any column for this, then check whether your primary is autoincremental?

Answer (score 1):

`No`, you can find out the result if you have primary key auto-incremental. But there is possibility that two consecutive rows may have inserted on different day/month/year. So, `only depending on the primary you can't find out the recent records.`

Comment: Correct. Unlike other DBMS, MySQL does not keep track of insertion times (or even insertion order).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a primary key field, (and that Primary Key need not be an AUTO INCREMENT one), then this can be achieved like

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY _rowid DESC
```